# Automatically divide text between two tikz paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-manipulation

I make a custom shape and I need to put a text inside it. But problem is that my text didn't fit the length of decorated path. So, I need a way to automatically divide text between two or three paths.

So, this is my shape and lines inside it is a place where I want to put my text:
[image]

I generate this shape with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% shape
\draw (0,0) ++ (45:3) arc (45:135:3);
\draw (0,0) ++ (45:5) arc (45:135:5);
\draw (45:3) -- (45:5);
\draw (135:3) -- (135:5);

%lines for text
\draw (0,0) ++ (50:3.5) arc (50:130:3.5);
\draw (0,0) ++ (50:4) arc (50:130:4);
\draw (0,0) ++ (50:4.5) arc (50:130:4.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I plan to put text to this lines using the path decoration:

```
\path[
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      text along path,
      reverse path=true,
      text={very long long text, which don't fit the shape boundaries}
    }
  }
] (0,0) ++ (50:4.5) arc (50:130:4.5);
```

But if the text is long, it's don't fit the provided space.

[image]

So I have to find a way to calculate a provided space and then divide the text between the several paths. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a single path (with several segments). *(Note the "bug": TikZ uses each segment in reverse order...)*

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% shape
\draw (0,0) ++ (45:3) arc (45:135:3);
\draw (0,0) ++ (45:5) arc (45:135:5);
\draw (45:3) -- (45:5);
\draw (135:3) -- (135:5);

%lines for text
\draw[blue] (0,0) ++ (50:3.5) arc (50:130:3.5);
\draw (0,0) ++ (50:4) arc (50:130:4);
\draw (0,0) ++ (50:4.5) arc (50:130:4.5);

% text along path
\path[
postaction={
  decorate,
  decoration={
    text along path,
    reverse path=true,
    text={Very long long text, which don't fit the shape boundaries
      and so on. Very long long text... Very long text...}
  }
}
]
(0,0) ++ (50:3.5) arc (50:130:3.5)
(0,0) ++ (50:4) arc (50:130:4)
(0,0) ++ (50:4.5) arc (50:130:4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here a complete solution without the `reverse path` option (to avoid the "bug") and without `(0,0)` (to fit the shape in the bounding box).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % shape
  \draw (45:3) arc (45:135:3)
  -- (135:5)  arc (135:45:5)
  -- cycle;

  % lines for text
  \draw
  (50:3.5) arc (50:130:3.5)
  (50:4) arc (50:130:4)
  (50:4.5) arc (50:130:4.5);

  % text along path
  \path[postaction={decorate,decoration={
      text along path,
      text={Very long long text, which don't fit the shape boundaries
        and so on. Very long long text... Very long text...}
    }}]
  (130:4.5) arc (130:50:4.5)
  (130:4) arc (130:50:4)
  (130:3.5) arc (130:50:3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `reverse path` you could always draw the arcs in a "left-to-right" way, for example `(130:3.5) arc (130:50:3.5)`. Also the arcs would need to be drawn "top-to-bottom" by drawing the arc with the largest radius first.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Excellent point! Thanks ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit thx for great suggestion.